# BigQuery max query length characters work around

Tags: google-bigquery

First let me explain the problem.
I have 500 unique users. The data from each of these users is split into smaller gzip files(lets say on an average 25 files per user). We have loaded each split gzip file as a separate table in BiqQuery. Therefore, our dataset has 13000 something tables in it.

Now, We have to run time range queries to retrieve some data from each user. We have around 500-1000 different time ranges from a single user. We would like to combine all these time ranges into a single query with logical OR and AND

```
  WHERE (timestamp >2 and timestamp <3) OR (timestamp >4 and timestamp <5) OR .............. and so on 1000 times
```

and run them on 13000 tables

Our own tests show that Bigquery has query length limit of 10000 characters?

If we split the conditions into multiple queries we exceed 20,000 daily quota limit.

IS there any work around this, so that we could run these queries without hitting the daily quota limit?

Thanks

JR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two things:

- Try reducing the number of tables in the dataset. If they share the same schema, would they be able to combined (denormalised) into a table, or at least less number of tables ?

I have loaded 500000+ JSON gzip files into one table, and querying is much easier.

- With timestamp, you can try to use a shorter common denominator.

for example instead of

```
WHERE (timestamp > "2014-06-25:00:00:00" AND timestamp < "2014-06-26:00:00:00")
```

You could express

```
WHERE LEFT(timestamp,10) = "2014-06-25"
```

Hopefully this can reduce your character length limit as well.

Comment: Assuming your timestamp column  actually has a TIMESTAMP type, you'll get an error when you run LEFT() on it. Use this instead: WHERE DATE(timestamp) = "2014-06-25"

Comment: Thanks we were already considering reducing tables. That should definitely work. Merging them separately is not an option, as the data is in order of 1.5 TB. Somehow, missed that loading different files with same schema into same big query table appends the entries into rows. so ended up loading everything separately in first place. Seems have to reload everything again :-)

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue of Big Query SQL Query length limit of 1024K characters when I am passing a big list of the array in WHERE condition.

To resolve it I used a parameterized query. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

Comment: How does that solve it? Is there not limit on the length/number of parameters in a parameterized query?

Comment: @TheDarkLord, yes this solves it. The 1024K char limit is for the query string, this provides the parameters by different means I assume.

Answer (score 3):

The big query payload limit, when you use parameterized queries is increased to 10MB instead of 1MB. That helped me.

This is the error message that I got when I tried out to find the limit for payload size of parameterized queries:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```